# CakePHP only validate when isset

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am using CakePHP 2.1. How can I configure the validator in my model that it does only do its job, if the form-field is set (my image upload is optional)?

```
public $validate = array(
    'question_image' => array(
        'ruleExtension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')),
            'message' => 'Das Bild hat ein ungültiges Format. Es sind nur gif, jpeg, png und jpg erlaubt.'
        ),
        'ruleFilesize' => array(
            'rule' => array('MaxFileSize'),
            'message' => 'Das Bild muss kleiner als 5 Megabyte sein.'
        ));
```

Comment: By "is set", do you mean has content, or do you mean only if the field is passed?

Comment: @Dave: when I send a form and have not selected an image (not required field).

Comment: Ayo is correct in his answer below then.

Answer (score 2):

set 'allowEmpty' => true in your rule's property

Comment: allowEmpty does not work on file upload and extension rule (.jpg, etc...). the rule 'required' => false does also not work.